# Trigger a event on Zoom change SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I want an event to be triggered when zoom of the map changes. I am using
sapui5 google maps.  In my view.xml i bound the map as following

```
<gmaps:Map id="map1" class="googleMap" height="600px" width="100%" zoom="4" lat="100" lng=100" markers="{/co}" ready="onMapReady"  zoomControl = 'true' 
zoom_changed  = "renderNewMap">
```

But it doesn't trigger the event.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventsOverview a couple of lines of code to a add zoom_changed handler, contributions welcome

Comment: just checked zoom_change event already been handled in the code, further to that idle is triggered also, therefore no need to add your own event as the "ready" event is fired

Comment: Please don't delete posts that people have just answered for you.  It makes us regret even trying to help you in the first place.  You can accept an answer that has been provided to show the community you now understand the solution.

Comment: Which post are you referring to??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid John Patterson's Google Maps control doesn't have a zoom event. According to [Map.js on Github](https://github.com/jasper07/openui5-googlemaps/blob/master/openui5/googlemaps/Map-dbg.js), only a `click` and `ready` event are present.

However, this control is open source though, meaning that you have the possibility to add whatever you think is missing in a subclass, or even your own version of this control.

If you make any useful modifications that could be useful for other people as well, it would also show good etiquette, if you could submit your changes in a pull request. In the open source community this is considered saying "thank  you". When you make a pull request, John could then easily include your contributions in future releases of the Google Maps control.